# Setting class dynamically with Rails using Slim

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4, slim-lang

I'm trying to figure out how I can set dynamic classes in slim (Rails 4).  This is what I'm trying...based on how I do it in erb.

```
li class="<%= 'current' if user.id == current_user.id  %>"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do!

```
li class="#{'current' if user.id == current_user.id}"
```

Basically, `class=anything_that_evaluates_to_string`. This works for all kinds of attributes.